Problems authenticating users using SSSD/Kerberos against an AD Forest on AlmaLinux/Rocky Linux 9
I have upgraded CentOS 7 AD clients to Alma/Rocky 9 but something must have changed because I cannot use AD for user logins anymore.
There always was a problem.  When we set up the system 10 years ago we couldn't get SSSD to log us in (auth) using AD because we have an AD forest.  We somehow went straight to Kerberos for authentication because that works.
Now I am trying to re-create the config but I have so far only recreated the problem:

realm leave and realm join worked

kinit testuser works and klist shows a Kerberos TGT (ticket granting ticket)

id testuser works (after only two days of trying parameters in /etc/sssd/sssd.conf)

Login by ssh -l testuser gives Permission denied, please try again., some log entries that looked suspicious from /var/log/sssd/sssd_ad.example.org.log below:
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [dp_attach_req] (0x0400): [RID#27] DP Request [PAM Preauth #27]: REQ_TRACE: New request. [sssd.pam CID #1] Flags [0000].
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [dp_attach_req] (0x0400): [RID#27] Number of active DP request: 1
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [sss_domain_get_state] (0x1000): [RID#27] Domain ad.example.org is Active
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [sss_domain_get_state] (0x1000): [RID#27] Domain login.example.org is Active
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [krb5_auth_queue_send] (0x1000): [RID#27] Wait queue of user [testuser@login.example.org] is empty, running request [0x55cc4fb6e200] immediately.
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [sss_domain_get_state] (0x1000): [RID#27] Domain ad.example.org is Active
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [sss_domain_get_state] (0x1000): [RID#27] Domain login.example.org is Active
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [krb5_setup] (0x4000): [RID#27] No mapping for: testuser@login.example.org
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [krb5_auth_send] (0x0100): [RID#27] Home directory for user [testuser@login.example.org] not known.
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [check_ccache_re] (0x1000): [RID#27] Ccache directory name [KCM:] does not contain illegal patterns.
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [krb5_auth_prepare_ccache_name] (0x1000): [RID#27] No ccache file for user [testuser@login.example.org] found.
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [fo_resolve_service_send] (0x0100): [RID#27] Trying to resolve service 'KERBEROS'
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [get_port_status] (0x1000): [RID#27] Port status of port 0 for server '(no name)' is 'neutral'
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [fo_resolve_service_activate_timeout] (0x2000): [RID#27] Resolve timeout [dns_resolver_timeout] set to 6 seconds
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [resolve_srv_send] (0x0200): [RID#27] The status of SRV lookup is neutral
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [ad_cldap_ping_send] (0x0400): [RID#27] CLDAP ping is not necessary, using site 'Example' and forest 'ad.example.org'
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [ad_srv_plugin_ping_done] (0x0400): [RID#27] About to discover primary and backup servers
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [fo_discover_servers_send] (0x0400): [RID#27] Looking up primary servers
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [resolv_discover_srv_next_domain] (0x0400): [RID#27] SRV resolution of service 'KERBEROS'. Will use DNS discovery domain 'EXAMPLE._sites.ad.example.org'
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [resolv_getsrv_send] (0x0100): [RID#27] Trying to resolve SRV record of '_KERBEROS._udp.EXAMPLE._sites.ad.example.org'
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [schedule_request_timeout] (0x2000): [RID#27] Scheduling a timeout of 3 seconds
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [schedule_timeout_watcher] (0x2000): [RID#27] Scheduling DNS timeout watcher
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [unschedule_timeout_watcher] (0x4000): [RID#27] Unscheduling DNS timeout watcher
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [request_watch_destructor] (0x0400): [RID#27] Deleting request watch
*  (2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [resolv_discover_srv_done] (0x0040): [RID#27] SRV query failed [4]: Domain name not found



The error messages do seem so vary somehow when playing with parameters.  However, one id and one ssh -l testuser localhost generate 490229 lines of debug info in sssd_ad.example.org.log which make it difficult for me to direct my attempts to a particular option.
Here is /etc/krb5.conf (names changed to protect the innocent):
# Configuration snippets may be placed in this directory as well
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/
includedir /var/lib/sss/pubconf/krb5.include.d/

[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default_realm = LOGIN.EXAMPLE.ORG
### default_realm = AD.EXAMPLE.ORG

 dns_lookup_realm = false
### false only when giving names below
 dns_lookup_kdc = true

 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 rdns = false
 default_ccache_name = FILE:/tmp/krbcc_%{uid}

[realms]
 AD.EXAMPLE.ORG = {
 kdc = ad-dc-01.ad.example.org
 kdc = ad-dc-02.ad.example.org
 }

 LOGIN.EXAMPLE.ORG = {
 kdc = ad-dc-01.ad.example.org
 kdc = ad-dc-02.ad.example.org
 }

[domain_realm]
 ad.example.org = AD.EXAMPLE.ORG
 .ad.example.org = AD.EXAMPLE.ORG
 login.example.org = LOGIN.EXAMPLE.ORG
 .login.example.org = LOGIN.EXAMPLE.ORG

Here is /etc/sssd/sssd.conf:
[sssd]
domains = ad.example.org
config_file_version = 2
### services = nss, pam
services = autofs, nss, pam
### services = nss

debug_level = 0x3ff0


[domain/ad.example.org]

ad_domain = ad.example.org
krb5_realm = AD.EXAMPLE.ORG
### realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba 
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli

# offline logins
### cache_credentials = True
### krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = false
krb5_store_password_if_offline = false

### must for id lookup: id_provider = ad
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
### access_provider = krb5
### Test since SSSD cannot do auth
### auth_provider = none
### auth_provider = ad
auth_provider = krb5
chpass_provider = krb5

enumerate = True

sudo_provider = none
selinux_provider = none

default_shell = /bin/bash
override_shell = /bin/bash

ldap_sasl_authid = hostname1$
ldap_id_mapping = True
### ldap_id_mapping = False

### test workaround, see https://pagure.io/SSSD/sssd/issue/3197
ldap_referrals = False
ad_enable_gc = False

use_fully_qualified_names = False
### disables lookup     use_fully_qualified_names = True

fallback_homedir = /home/%u

### krb5_validate = False
krb5_validate = true

debug_level = 0x3ff0

[domain/ad.example.org/login.example.org]
use_fully_qualified_names = False

debug_level = 0x3ff0

[domain/login.example.org]
use_fully_qualified_names = False

debug_level = 0x3ff0

[domain/vdi.example.org]
use_fully_qualified_names = False

debug_level = 0x3ff0


[nss]
debug_level = 0x3ff0

[pam]
debug_level = 0x3ff0

[autofs]
debug_level = 0x3ff0

EDIT: New /etc/krb5.conf explicitly listing domain controllers in realms.  New error message is:
# systemctl status sssd 

● sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sssd.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-11-09 17:45:52 CET; 1min 38s ago
   Main PID: 9343 (sssd)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 98286)
     Memory: 48.6M
        CPU: 149ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/sssd.service
             ├─9343 /usr/sbin/sssd -i --logger=files
             ├─9345 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_be --domain ad.example.org --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
             ├─9346 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_autofs --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
             ├─9347 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_nss --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
             ├─9348 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pam --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
             └─9349 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pac --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files

Nov 09 17:45:52 hostname1.ad.example.org sssd[9343]: Starting up
Nov 09 17:45:52 hostname1.ad.example.org sssd_be[9345]: Starting up
Nov 09 17:45:52 hostname1.ad.example.org sssd_autofs[9346]: Starting up
Nov 09 17:45:52 hostname1.ad.example.org sssd_nss[9347]: Starting up
Nov 09 17:45:52 hostname1.ad.example.org sssd_pam[9348]: Starting up
Nov 09 17:45:52 hostname1.ad.example.org sssd_pac[9349]: Starting up
Nov 09 17:45:52 hostname1.ad.example.org systemd[1]: Started System Security Services Daemon.
Nov 09 17:45:52 hostname1.ad.example.org sssd_be[9345]: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Decrypt integrity check failed)
Nov 09 17:45:52 hostname1.ad.example.org sssd_be[9345]: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Decrypt integrity check failed)
Nov 09 17:45:52 hostname1.ad.example.org sssd_be[9345]: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Decrypt integrity check failed)

Now the id command fails.

(2024-11-09 16:24:34): [be[ad.example.org]] [resolv_discover_srv_done] (0x0040): [RID#27] SRV query failed [4]: Domain name not found what SRV records exist, and what does nslookup show for the records?

The host command gives: Host _KERBEROS._udp.EXAMPLE._sites.ad.example.org not found: 3(NXDOMAIN). Should it exist, or is it wrongly set? (Sorry I am not one of the AD admins.) Or, should it be looked up in a non-DNS way?

Whoever issued a non-specific close vote kindly comment what seems to be the problem.  From my point of view RHEL 9 and clones as well as Kerberos, AD and SSSD are very much common and current software. All have a large number of tagged questions on this very site.  If this question should be placed on a different SE site please specify which one.

Have you tried to activate AD-SUPPORT or AD-SUPPORT-LEGACY module using update-crypto-policies:
update-crypto-policies DEFAULT:AD-SUPPORT

or
update-crypto-policies DEFAULT:AD-SUPPORT-LEGACY

You may need to substitute "DEFAULT" with your current crypto policy.
I would also recommend looking at adcli utility and use that to enroll clients to the AD domain. It caused some issues in RHEL 7 and/or 8 but AFAIR it works correctly in RHEL 9 and derivatives (I certainly used it to enroll Almalinux-9 clients to AD with success).
The following line:
ldap_sasl_authid = hostname1$

MIGHT be a culprit.  Computer client principal is usually stored in AD kerberos database UPPERCASE (i.e. HOSTNAME1$). And Linux IS case-sensitive. Please check that this line matches with what's in AD kerberos database.

Thanks, the ldap_sasl_authid definitely must be UPPERCASE, thanks for spotting that! I have also set the crypto policies and have rebooted. However, I still have problems. I keep getting Realm not local to KD when connecting to the only KDC I have, ad-dc-01.ad.example.org, about testuser@LOGIN.EXAMPLE.ORG.

So, are you connecting to LOGIN.EXAMPLE.ORG as specified in krb5.conf or to AD.EXAMPLE.ORG as specified in sssd.conf? Would https://serverfault.com/questions/166768/kinit-wont-connect-to-a-domain-server-realm-not-local-to-kdc-while-getting-in be of any help here? I would suggest starting clean and just doing adcli...

I have joined again with adcli and have started reading the linked material, so far to no avail. The problem is that we can only contact ad.example.com (we joined there) but this is a secondary Forest-y instance to the real master, login.example.com, for our domain example.com. So we need to juggle these three, and I get Realm not local to KD again and again as I try to query ad and re-direct login queries (expanded automatically to @LOGIN...) to ad (since we are unknown to the login server).

That's something I didn't tackle so cannot help here... The only advice I can give is to have a look at sssd.conf man page and trusted domain section. I don't know however if it can help and how it works with domains which don't share common DNS parent (I had some success with using sssd in the forest but never really needed to explore it beyond using single domain).
